# Elementor Pro Loop Grip Posts Filter Orderby Not Working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce, elementor

[image: Elementor Pro]

Here is my Loop Grid Orderby values which is set to now price with DESC value... that works just fine... I just want to dynamically change these orderby and order value via `elementor/query/query_args` which I found somewhere online...

```
add_filter( 'elementor/query/query_args', 'advanced_query_args', 100, 2 );

function advanced_query_args( $query_args, $widget )
{
    if( isset( $_GET['custom_orderby_price_asc'] ) )
    {
        $query_args[ 'orderby' ] = 'price';
        
        $query_args[ 'order' ] = 'asc';
    }
    
    return $query_args;
}
```

For some reason this is not working... the filter is not working, page shows same products in the order it is set in Elementor section... same for all other orderby values (Date, Title, Popularity, Rating etc) not working!! Anyone have any idea why it's not working or is there any other filter to use for that use case!! thanks!!

Comment: Make sure that the `advanced_query_args` function is hooked to the `elementor/query/query_args` filter at the appropriate priority. You can try reducing the priority value to 10 or 20 to ensure it runs before other filters.

Comment: @Bhautik changing priority to any value 10, 20, 100 or PHP_INT_MAX doesn't affect the query unfortunately!!